# How to create a scrollable radio button list in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I create a wizard to allow user choose from the selection from radio button but I encounter the problem when the selection is more then a dialog size, it will not show the rest of the selection as figure below:

[image]

I wish to use the scroll down bar but really hard to find the tutorial online. Anyone can help on this?

```pascal
for code := 0 to 9 do
begin
  CheckBox := TNewCheckListBox.Create(Page);
  CheckBox.Parent := Page.Surface;
  CheckBox.AddCheckBox('test', '', 0, True, False, False, True, nil);
  CheckBox.AddRadioButton('1', '', 1, True, True, nil );
  CheckBox.AddRadioButton('2', '', 1, False,True, nil );
end
```

Comment: Do you create the radio button list manually (using pascal scripting)? Or is it a task list created by Inno Setup from `[Tasks]` section?

Comment: Below is my sneak code. *It got a looping in code

`code`
for 0 to 9 do begin
CheckBox:= TNewCheckListBox.Create(Page);
CheckBox.Parent := Page.Surface; 
CheckBox.AddCheckBox("test", '', 0, True, False, False, True, nil);
CheckBox.AddRadioButton('1', '', 1, True, True, nil );
CheckBox.AddRadioButton('2', '', 1, False,True, nil );
end
`code`

Martin, i'm using the pascal scripting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one big `TNewCheckListBox` for all checkboxes and radiobuttons, instead of creating a separate box for each set. The `TNewCheckListBox` will automatically show scrollbar, if its contents does not fit.

```pascal
function CustomPage(var Page:TWizardPage;PageId:Integer):Integer;
var
  CheckListBox: TNewCheckListBox;       
begin
  Page:=CreateCustomPage(PageId,ExpandConstant('AAA'),ExpandConstant('BBB'));
  CheckListBox:=TNewCheckListBox.Create(Page);
  with CheckListBox do begin       
    Parent:=Page.Surface;          
    Left:=ScaleX(0);
    Top:=ScaleY(50);
    Width:=ScaleX(413);
    Height:=ScaleY(153);              
    AddCheckBox(ExpandConstant('Test'),'',0,False,True,False,True,Nil);
    AddRadioButton(ExpandConstant('1'),'',1,True,True,Nil);               
    AddRadioButton(ExpandConstant('2'),'',1,False,True,Nil);                    
    AddCheckBox(ExpandConstant('Test'),'',0,False,True,False,True,Nil);
    AddRadioButton(ExpandConstant('1'),'',1,True,True,Nil);               
    AddRadioButton(ExpandConstant('2'),'',1,False,True,Nil);
    AddCheckBox(ExpandConstant('Test'),'',0,False,True,False,True,Nil);
    AddRadioButton(ExpandConstant('1'),'',1,True,True,Nil);               
    AddRadioButton(ExpandConstant('2'),'',1,False,True,Nil);
    AddCheckBox(ExpandConstant('Test'),'',0,False,True,False,True,Nil);
    AddRadioButton(ExpandConstant('1'),'',1,True,True,Nil);               
    AddRadioButton(ExpandConstant('2'),'',1,False,True,Nil);
  end;
  Result:=Page.ID;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  NewPage: TWizardPage;       
  NewPageID:Integer;                  
begin            
  NewPageID:=CustomPage(NewPage,wpWelcome);     
end;
```

Example 2:

```
function CustomPage(var Page:TWizardPage;PageId:Integer):Integer;
var
  CheckBox: TNewCheckListBox;     
  I:Integer;
begin
  Page:=CreateCustomPage(PageId,ExpandConstant('AAA'),ExpandConstant('BBB'));
  CheckBox:=TNewCheckListBox.Create(Page);
  with CheckBox do begin       
    Parent:=Page.Surface;       
    Left := ScaleX(0);
    Top := ScaleY(56);
    Width := ScaleX(413);
    Height := ScaleY(153);
    for I:=0 to 9 do begin       
      AddCheckBox('test', '', 0, True, False, False, True, nil); 
      AddRadioButton('1', '', 1, True, True, nil ); 
      AddRadioButton('2', '', 1, False,True, nil );             
    end;
  end;
end;
```

[image]